# как с помощью $_GET получить значение

Tags: php, сессия, get

есть ссылка: http:// www.cr.com /act.php?key=YWFAYWEuYWE (без пробелов)

в файлк act.php следующий код:

```html
<?php
 
 $key = $_GET['key'];
 $_SESSION['key'] = $key;
 header("location: http://cr.com/error/");
 
?>

код страницы error:

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
 
 <head>
 
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  
  <title></title>
  
 </head>
 
 <body>
 
  <div>
   
   <h4>
   
    <?php 
     
     if($_SESSION['key'] != "")
     {
      echo $_SESSION['key'];
      $_SESSION['key']="";
     }
     
    ?>
  
   </h4>
   
  </div>
 
 </body>
 
</html>
```

при клике на ссылку меня перекидывает на пустую страницу error. т.е. echo $_SESSION['key']; не срабатывает.

что я делаю не так? почему не получается считать YWFAYWEuYWE из ссылки?

PS: недавно изучаю php, сорри, если где то ступил...